# Analyzing yet another Windows 7 minidump

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windbg

I am trying to fix a WIn7 64B pc with BOSD-issues using remote access. So I cannot use dirver verifier.

So far I used windbg on the minidump getting this:

```
2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff800028e1c3f, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for fwwfp764.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for fwwfp764.sys

WRITE_ADDRESS:  0000000000000000 Nonpaged pool

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel+4f
fffff800`028e1c3f 488713          xchg    rdx,qword ptr [rbx]

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff880027674f0 -- (.trap 0xfffff880027674f0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=fffffa8004c73510 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=fffff880027676f0 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff800028e1c3f rsp=fffff88002767680 rbp=0000000000000004
 r8=fffff880027676f0  r9=fffff8800178acb0 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000040 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
nt!KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x4f:
fffff800`028e1c3f 488713          xchg    rdx,qword ptr [rbx] ds:00000000`00000000=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800028d8169 to fffff800028d8bc0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`027673a8 fffff800`028d8169 : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000001 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`027673b0 fffff800`028d6de0 : 00000000`00000010 fffff880`027676e0 fffff880`00000003 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`027674f0 fffff800`028e1c3f : 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000002 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`02767680 fffff880`0152c9c7 : 00000000`00000004 fffff880`02767960 00000000`00008900 fffffa80`0467d7c8 : nt!KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x4f
fffff880`027676d0 fffff880`016e608d : fffffa80`06a4ce10 fffffa80`04ee6320 fffff880`02767960 00000000`00008900 : NETIO!WfpExpireEntryLru+0x17
fffff880`02767720 fffff880`016ad7b7 : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000030 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : tcpip!WfpAleCloseRemoteEndpointConnection+0x2d
fffff880`02767750 fffff880`01725e5b : fffffa80`06a4ce10 fffffa80`03b27baa fffff880`02767b40 fffffa80`06a4ce10 : tcpip! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x20f72
fffff880`027678a0 fffff880`017261e2 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`03b27ae0 00000000`00000001 fffff880`02767b40 : tcpip!WfpAleHandleSendCompletion+0xeb
fffff880`027679c0 fffff880`017306b2 : fffffa80`040b7ec0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : tcpip!WfpAlepAuthorizeSendCompletion+0x32
fffff880`02767a10 fffff880`01592af2 : fffffa80`0458b820 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`03b27ae0 fffff880`02767b40 : tcpip!WfpAleCompleteOperation+0x162
fffff880`02767ab0 fffff880`02aa41cb : fffffa80`03b27ae0 fffff880`02767b40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : fwpkclnt!FwpsCompleteOperation0+0x1e
fffff880`02767ae0 fffffa80`03b27ae0 : fffff880`02767b40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`04b99700 : fwwfp764+0x61cb
fffff880`02767ae8 fffff880`02767b40 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`04b99700 fffff880`02aa1392 : 0xfffffa80`03b27ae0
fffff880`02767af0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`04b99700 fffff880`02aa1392 fffffa80`04c79b48 : 0xfffff880`02767b40


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
NETIO!WfpExpireEntryLru+17
fffff880`0152c9c7 488b4310        mov     rax,qword ptr [rbx+10h]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  NETIO!WfpExpireEntryLru+17

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: NETIO

IMAGE_NAME:  NETIO.SYS

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5294760d

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18327

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_NETIO!WfpExpireEntryLru+17

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_NETIO!WfpExpireEntryLru+17

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xa_netio!wfpexpireentrylru+17

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {fcdee258-ad7b-b100-5f3a-ac9544c5fd1f}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

and I used bluescreenview which marked just ntoskrnl.exe in red:

```
`ntoskrnl.exe   ntoskrnl.exe+f20d4  fffff800`02863000   fffff800`02e48000   0x005e5000  0x531590fb  04.03.2014 09:38:19 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NT Kernel & System  6.1.7601.18409 (win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe    
hal.dll     fffff800`0281a000   fffff800`02863000   0x00049000  0x4ce7c669  20.11.2010 14:00:25 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Hardware Abstraction Layer DLL  6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\hal.dll 
kdcom.dll       fffff800`03017000   fffff800`03021000   0x0000a000  0x4d4d8061  05.02.2011 17:52:49 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Serial Kernel Debugger  6.1.7601.17556 (win7sp1_gdr.110204-2120)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\kdcom.dll   
mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll       fffff880`00cbd000   fffff880`00d0c000   0x0004f000  0x4ce7c737  20.11.2010 14:03:51 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Intel Microcode Update Library  6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll   
PSHED.dll       fffff880`00d0c000   fffff880`00d20000   0x00014000  0x4a5be027  14.07.2009 02:32:23 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Plattformspezifischer Hardwarefehlertreiber 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\PSHED.dll   
CLFS.SYS        fffff880`00d20000   fffff880`00d7e000   0x0005e000  0x4a5bc11d  14.07.2009 00:19:57 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Common Log File System Driver   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\CLFS.SYS    
CI.dll      fffff880`00e30000   fffff880`00ef0000   0x000c0000  0x4ce7c944  20.11.2010 14:12:36 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Codeintegritätsmodul    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\CI.dll  
Wdf01000.sys        fffff880`00ef0000   fffff880`00fb2000   0x000c2000  0x51c51641  22.06.2013 04:13:05 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Kernelmodustreiber-Frameworklaufzeit    1.11.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\Wdf01000.sys    
WDFLDR.SYS      fffff880`00fb2000   fffff880`00fc2000   0x00010000  0x5010ab70  26.07.2012 03:29:04 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Kernel Mode Driver Framework Loader 1.11.9200.16384 (win8_rtm.120725-1247)  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\WDFLDR.SYS  
ACPI.sys        fffff880`00d7e000   fffff880`00dd5000   0x00057000  0x4ce79294  20.11.2010 10:19:16 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  ACPI-Treiber für NT 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ACPI.sys    
WMILIB.SYS      fffff880`00fc2000   fffff880`00fcb000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc117  14.07.2009 00:19:51 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    WMILIB WMI support library Dll  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\WMILIB.SYS  
msisadrv.sys        fffff880`00fcb000   fffff880`00fd5000   0x0000a000  0x4a5bc0fe  14.07.2009 00:19:26 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    ISA Driver  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\msisadrv.sys    
pci.sys     fffff880`00c00000   fffff880`00c33000   0x00033000  0x4ce7928f  20.11.2010 10:19:11 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  NT-Plug & Play PCI-Enumerator   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\pci.sys 
vdrvroot.sys        fffff880`00fd5000   fffff880`00fe2000   0x0000d000  0x4a5bcadb  14.07.2009 01:01:31 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Stammenumerator für virtuelles Laufwerk 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vdrvroot.sys    
iusb3hcs.sys        fffff880`00fe2000   fffff880`00feb000   0x00009000  0x4f227053  27.01.2012 10:37:23 USB 3.0 Host Controller Switch Driver   Intel(R) USB 3.0 Host Controller Switch Driver  1.0.3.214 built by: WinDDK  Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\iusb3hcs.sys    
partmgr.sys     fffff880`00feb000   fffff880`01000000   0x00015000  0x4f641bc1  17.03.2012 06:06:09 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Partition Management Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\partmgr.sys 
volmgr.sys      fffff880`00e00000   fffff880`00e15000   0x00015000  0x4ce792a0  20.11.2010 10:19:28 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Volume Manager Driver   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\volmgr.sys  
volmgrx.sys     fffff880`00c33000   fffff880`00c8f000   0x0005c000  0x00000000      Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Treiber für Erweiterung des Volume-Managers 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\volmgrx.sys 
mountmgr.sys        fffff880`00e15000   fffff880`00e2f000   0x0001a000  0x4ce79299  20.11.2010 10:19:21 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Bereitstellungspunkt-Manager    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\mountmgr.sys    
atapi.sys       fffff880`00c8f000   fffff880`00c98000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc113  14.07.2009 00:19:47 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    ATAPI IDE Miniport Driver   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\atapi.sys   
ataport.SYS     fffff880`00dd5000   fffff880`00dff000   0x0002a000  0x51fef9b5  05.08.2013 02:02:45 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    ATAPI Driver Extension  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ataport.SYS 
msahci.sys      fffff880`00c98000   fffff880`00ca3000   0x0000b000  0x4ce7a416  20.11.2010 11:33:58 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    MS AHCI 1.0 Standard Driver 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\msahci.sys  
PCIIDEX.SYS     fffff880`00ca3000   fffff880`00cb3000   0x00010000  0x4a5bc114  14.07.2009 00:19:48 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    PCI IDE Bus Driver Extension    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\PCIIDEX.SYS 
amdxata.sys     fffff880`01096000   fffff880`010a1000   0x0000b000  0x4ba3a3ca  19.03.2010 17:18:18 Storage Filter Driver   Storage Filter Driver   1.1.2.5 (NT.091202-1659)    Advanced Micro Devices  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\amdxata.sys 
fltmgr.sys      fffff880`010a1000   fffff880`010ed000   0x0004c000  0x4ce7929c  20.11.2010 10:19:24 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Microsoft Dateisystem-Filter-Manager    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys  
fileinfo.sys        fffff880`010ed000   fffff880`01101000   0x00014000  0x4a5bc481  14.07.2009 00:34:25 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    FileInfo Filter Driver  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fileinfo.sys    
Ntfs.sys        fffff880`0123f000   fffff880`013e8000   0x001a9000  0x52e1be8a  24.01.2014 02:14:50 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  NT-Dateisystemtreiber   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\Ntfs.sys    
msrpc.sys       fffff880`01101000   fffff880`0115f000   0x0005e000  0x4ce79334  20.11.2010 10:21:56 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Kernel Remote Procedure Call Provider   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\msrpc.sys   
ksecdd.sys      fffff880`01200000   fffff880`0121b000   0x0001b000  0x5348920e  12.04.2014 02:08:30 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Kernel Security Support Provider Interface  6.1.7601.18443 (win7sp1_gdr.140411-1533)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ksecdd.sys  
cng.sys     fffff880`0115f000   fffff880`011d1000   0x00072000  0x50194fb7  01.08.2012 16:48:07 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Kernel Cryptography, Next Generation    6.1.7601.17919 (win7sp1_gdr.120801-0333)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\cng.sys 
pcw.sys     fffff880`0121b000   fffff880`0122c000   0x00011000  0x4a5bc0ff  14.07.2009 00:19:27 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Performance Counters for Windows Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\pcw.sys 
Fs_Rec.sys      fffff880`0122c000   fffff880`01236000   0x0000a000  0x4f4eefd2  01.03.2012 04:41:06 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    File System Recognizer Driver   6.1.7601.17787 (win7sp1_gdr.120229-1502)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\Fs_Rec.sys  
ndis.sys        fffff880`0140f000   fffff880`01501000   0x000f2000  0x5034f6b2  22.08.2012 16:11:46 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  NDIS 6.20-Treiber   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ndis.sys    
NETIO.SYS       fffff880`01501000   fffff880`01561000   0x00060000  0x5294760d  26.11.2013 11:21:01 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Network I/O Subsystem   6.1.7601.18327 (win7sp1_gdr.131125-2337)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\NETIO.SYS   
ksecpkg.sys     fffff880`01561000   fffff880`0158d000   0x0002c000  0x543c7790  14.10.2014 02:08:32 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Kernel Security Support Provider Interface Packages 6.1.7601.18637 (win7sp1_gdr.141013-1517)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ksecpkg.sys 
tcpip.sys       fffff880`01601000   fffff880`01800000   0x001ff000  0x533f5bd4  05.04.2014 02:26:44 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  TCP/IP-Treiber  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys   
fwpkclnt.sys        fffff880`0158d000   fffff880`015d6000   0x00049000  0x533f5b09  05.04.2014 02:23:21 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    FWP/IPsec Kernel-Mode API   6.1.7601.18438 (win7sp1_gdr.140404-1535)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fwpkclnt.sys    
vmstorfl.sys        fffff880`015d6000   fffff880`015e6000   0x00010000  0x4ce79b8a  20.11.2010 10:57:30 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Virtual Storage Filter Driver   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vmstorfl.sys    
volsnap.sys     fffff880`01000000   fffff880`0104c000   0x0004c000  0x4ce792c8  20.11.2010 10:20:08 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Volumeschattenkopie-Treiber 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\volsnap.sys 
spldr.sys       fffff880`015e6000   fffff880`015ee000   0x00008000  0x4a0858bb  11.05.2009 17:56:27 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    loader for security processor   6.1.7127.0 (fbl_security_bugfix(sepbld-s).090511-0943)  Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\spldr.sys   
rdyboost.sys        fffff880`0104c000   fffff880`01086000   0x0003a000  0x4ce7982e  20.11.2010 10:43:10 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    ReadyBoost Driver   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\rdyboost.sys    
mup.sys     fffff880`015ee000   fffff880`01600000   0x00012000  0x4a5bc201  14.07.2009 00:23:45 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Multiple UNC Provider Driver    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\mup.sys 
hwpolicy.sys        fffff880`01400000   fffff880`01409000   0x00009000  0x4ce7927e  20.11.2010 10:18:54 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Hardware Policy Driver  6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\hwpolicy.sys    
fvevol.sys      fffff880`018ff000   fffff880`01939000   0x0003a000  0x5100a65c  24.01.2013 04:11:24 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    BitLocker Drive Encryption Driver   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fvevol.sys  
disk.sys        fffff880`01939000   fffff880`0194f000   0x00016000  0x4a5bc11d  14.07.2009 00:19:57 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    PnP Disk Driver 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\disk.sys    
CLASSPNP.SYS        fffff880`0194f000   fffff880`0197f000   0x00030000  0x4ce7929b  20.11.2010 10:19:23 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    SCSI Class System Dll   6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\CLASSPNP.SYS    
cdrom.sys       fffff880`019b7000   fffff880`019e1000   0x0002a000  0x4ce79298  20.11.2010 10:19:20 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    SCSI CD-ROM Driver  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys   
a2dix64.sys     fffff880`019e1000   fffff880`019f0000   0x0000f000  0x5221c6af  31.08.2013 11:34:23                     
Null.SYS        fffff880`019f0000   fffff880`019f9000   0x00009000  0x4a5bc109  14.07.2009 00:19:37 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NULL Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\Null.SYS    
Beep.SYS        fffff880`019f9000   fffff880`01a00000   0x00007000  0x4a5bca8d  14.07.2009 01:00:13 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    BEEP Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\Beep.SYS    
vga.sys     fffff880`01800000   fffff880`0180e000   0x0000e000  0x4a5bc587  14.07.2009 00:38:47 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    VGA/Super VGA Video Driver  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vga.sys 
VIDEOPRT.SYS        fffff880`0180e000   fffff880`01833000   0x00025000  0x4a5bc58b  14.07.2009 00:38:51 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Video Port Driver   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\VIDEOPRT.SYS    
watchdog.sys        fffff880`01833000   fffff880`01843000   0x00010000  0x4a5bc53f  14.07.2009 00:37:35 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Watchdog Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\watchdog.sys    
RDPCDD.sys      fffff880`01843000   fffff880`0184c000   0x00009000  0x4a5bce62  14.07.2009 01:16:34 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    RDP Miniport    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\RDPCDD.sys  
rdpencdd.sys        fffff880`0184c000   fffff880`01855000   0x00009000  0x4a5bce62  14.07.2009 01:16:34 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    RDP Encoder Miniport    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\rdpencdd.sys    
rdprefmp.sys        fffff880`01855000   fffff880`0185e000   0x00009000  0x4a5bce63  14.07.2009 01:16:35 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    RDP Reflector Driver Miniport   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\rdprefmp.sys    
Msfs.SYS        fffff880`0185e000   fffff880`01869000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bc113  14.07.2009 00:19:47 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Mailslot driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\Msfs.SYS    
Npfs.SYS        fffff880`01869000   fffff880`0187a000   0x00011000  0x4a5bc114  14.07.2009 00:19:48 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NPFS Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\Npfs.SYS    
tdx.sys     fffff880`0187a000   fffff880`0189c000   0x00022000  0x54616a72  11.11.2014 02:46:26 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    TDI Translation Driver  6.1.7601.18658 (win7sp1_gdr.141110-1511)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\tdx.sys 
TDI.SYS     fffff880`0189c000   fffff880`018a9000   0x0000d000  0x4ce7933e  20.11.2010 10:22:06 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    TDI Wrapper 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\TDI.SYS 
fwtdi64.sys     fffff880`028f0000   fffff880`0299d000   0x000ad000  0x54a5a2a8  01.01.2015 20:40:24                     
afd.sys     fffff880`02800000   fffff880`02889000   0x00089000  0x5388291c  30.05.2014 07:45:48 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Ancillary Function Driver for WinSock   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\afd.sys 
netbt.sys       fffff880`02889000   fffff880`028ce000   0x00045000  0x4ce79386  20.11.2010 10:23:18 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    MBT Transport driver    6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\netbt.sys   
wfplwf.sys      fffff880`028ce000   fffff880`028d7000   0x00009000  0x4a5bccb6  14.07.2009 01:09:26 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    WFP NDIS 6.20 Lightweight Filter Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\wfplwf.sys  
pacer.sys       fffff880`0299d000   fffff880`029c3000   0x00026000  0x4ce7a862  20.11.2010 11:52:18 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  QoS-Paketplaner 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\pacer.sys   
netbios.sys     fffff880`029c3000   fffff880`029d2000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bccb6  14.07.2009 01:09:26 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NetBIOS interface driver    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\netbios.sys 
serial.sys      fffff880`029d2000   fffff880`029ef000   0x0001d000  0x4a5bcaa8  14.07.2009 01:00:40 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Serieller Gerätetreiber 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\serial.sys  
wanarp.sys      fffff880`018a9000   fffff880`018c4000   0x0001b000  0x4ce7a874  20.11.2010 11:52:36 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    MS Remote Access and Routing ARP Driver 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\wanarp.sys  
termdd.sys      fffff880`028d7000   fffff880`028eb000   0x00014000  0x4ce7ab0c  20.11.2010 12:03:40 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Remote Desktop Server Driver    6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\termdd.sys  
rdbss.sys       fffff880`02a36000   fffff880`02a87000   0x00051000  0x4ce79497  20.11.2010 10:27:51 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Subsystemtreiber für Pufferung des umgeleiteten Laufwerks   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\rdbss.sys   
nsiproxy.sys        fffff880`02a87000   fffff880`02a93000   0x0000c000  0x4a5bc15e  14.07.2009 00:21:02 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    NSI Proxy   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\nsiproxy.sys    
mssmbios.sys        fffff880`02a93000   fffff880`02a9e000   0x0000b000  0x4a5bc3be  14.07.2009 00:31:10 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    System Management BIOS Driver   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\mssmbios.sys    
fwwfp764.sys        fffff880`02a9e000   fffff880`02b06000   0x00068000  0x54a5a2d6  01.01.2015 20:41:10                     
discache.sys        fffff880`02b06000   fffff880`02b15000   0x0000f000  0x4a5bc52e  14.07.2009 00:37:18 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    System Indexer/Cache Driver 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\discache.sys    
dfsc.sys        fffff880`02b15000   fffff880`02b33000   0x0001e000  0x4ce79447  20.11.2010 10:26:31 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    DFS Namespace Client Driver 6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\dfsc.sys    
ctxusbm.sys     fffff880`02b33000   fffff880`02b47280   0x00014280  0x4dcc9fdc  13.05.2011 04:05:00 Citrix ICA Client   Citrix USB Filter Driver    12.1.10.6   Citrix Systems, Inc.    C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ctxusbm.sys 
csc.sys     fffff880`02b48000   fffff880`02bcb000   0x00083000  0x4ce79470  20.11.2010 10:27:12 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Windows Client Side Caching Driver  6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\csc.sys 
blbdrive.sys        fffff880`02bcb000   fffff880`02bdc000   0x00011000  0x4a5bc4df  14.07.2009 00:35:59 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    BLB Drive Driver    6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\blbdrive.sys    
a2util64.sys        fffff880`02bdc000   fffff880`02be6000   0x0000a000  0x537059be  12.05.2014 06:18:54                     
a2ddax64.sys        fffff880`02be6000   fffff880`02bf0000   0x0000a000  0x51396c04  08.03.2013 05:41:40                     
tunnel.sys      fffff880`02a00000   fffff880`02a26000   0x00026000  0x4ce7a846  20.11.2010 11:51:50 Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®  Microsoft-Tunnelschnittstellentreiber   6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\tunnel.sys  
iusb3xhc.sys        fffff880`0305d000   fffff880`03121000   0x000c4000  0x4f226fe0  27.01.2012 10:35:28 USB 3.0 Device Driver   Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller Driver  1.0.3.214 (iusb3drv.20120127-0133)  Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\iusb3xhc.sys    
USBD.SYS        fffff880`03121000   fffff880`03122e80   0x00001e80  0x52954daf  27.11.2013 02:41:03 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Universal Serial Bus Driver 6.1.7601.18328 (win7sp1_gdr.131126-1436)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\USBD.SYS    
HECIx64.sys     fffff880`03123000   fffff880`03136000   0x00013000  0x4ff21d62  02.07.2012 23:14:58 Intel(R) Management Engine Interface    Intel(R) Management Engine Interface    8.1.0.1263 built by: WinDDK Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\HECIx64.sys 
serenum.sys     fffff880`03136000   fffff880`03142000   0x0000c000  0x4a5bcaa1  14.07.2009 01:00:33 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    Serial Port Enumerator  6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)   Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\serenum.sys 
e1c62x64.sys        fffff880`03142000   fffff880`031bb000   0x00079000  0x50258ebf  10.08.2012 23:44:15 Intel(R) Gigabit Adapter    Intel(R) Gigabit Adapter NDIS 6.x driver    12.2.45.0 built by: WinDDK  Intel Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\e1c62x64.sys    
usbehci.sys     fffff880`031bb000   fffff880`031cd000   0x00012000  0x52954db7  27.11.2013 02:41:11 Microsoft® Windows® Operating System    EHCI eUSB Miniport Driver   6.1.7601.18328 (win7sp1_gdr.131126-1436)    Microsoft Corporation   C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbehci.sys
```

the rest of the list will be in comment, since it exceeds the limit of a single post.

Any idea who's the culprit here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Ok, I cannot post the rest of the list here either ... the characters limit is just too low. but maybe it wont be needed anyway or I'll just extract the name of the .sys. files if needed :)

Comment: Really? "Here's my dump file what's wrong"?  -1 for a complete lack of effort in both research and formatting.

Comment: first: I didnt provide a dump file but the output of windbg, second: there is so much info that I dont even know where to start my research. Looking up NETIO.SYS didn't help. third: I tried to mark that text as code but using 2x4 spaces like discribed didn't do anything. So instead of getting rude you could tell me how to do it properly.

Comment: Rude is not spending any time researching for yourself before asking us to do all the work for you (for free). You didn't even perform a basic Google search of the error codes you've received, at least not that we can tell. You say now you've searched on NETIO.sys, but didn't include that in your question so we'd know (for example).   For formatting the code, you highlight the code you want to have maintain it's formatting and then with the `{}` button in the editor to tell it is "preformatted" code. It sticks 4 spaces in front of each line to signify this.

Comment: Basically we're damned if we do, damned if we don't.  If we don't comment on why we down-vote people cry about it, when we do comment we're "rude".  Anyhow, glad you got your answer.

Comment: I spent 2 hours getting windbg to run properly because the stupid symbols wouldnt load for some reason. Yes, I forgot to mention, that I googled for NETIO.sys already. What do you mean by "doing all the work for you"? I just asked you to take a look at the windbg output because I simply couldnt interpret it and was looking for the answer in the wrong spot obviously like Ramhound found out. So it was impossible for me to find anything else worth googling for. Thats why I decided to make this post.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the {} button. When I made the post I clicked on "code" and put 4 spaces in front and 4 spaces at the end of the code block instead of in front of every line. Thats why it didn't work :)

Comment: Oh and most of the text was the bluescreenview log which I posted because someone trying to help asked for it in a similar thread so I figured it might be a good idea to provide it right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` bug check is caused by a kernel-mode driver attempting to access pageable memory at a process IRQL that was too high.  In other words Windows loaded a driver (specifically in kernel-mode) that didn't behave itself causing Windows' kernel crashed.

By default, it's faulting NETIO.sys which is the Network I/O Subsystem. This is not the true cause and is being faulted by something else. Usually, in most cases, this occurs frequently in Windows 7 > 8 or 8 > 8.1 updates because of two reasons:

1. Network drivers themselves need to be updated.
2. 3rd party antivirus, firewall software or other software is causing conflicts and or corruption.

WinDBG provided you all the information you required to figure this out.

> Debugging Details:
>
> WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for **fwwfp764.sys** 
>   ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for **fwwfp764.sys**

fwwfp764.sys belongs to software released by Emsisoft.  So uninstall your Emsisoft software and the crashes will go away.

[Emsisoft Support Thread](http://support.emsisoft.com/topic/16259-bsd-blue-screen-of-death-suddenly/)

Comment: Very cool, thanks a bunch! I thought the fwwfp764.sys warning was a problem of windbg while analyzing the file .. not the troublemaker itself :) I installed the MS Patch "Windows6.1-KB2958399-x64". Lets hope this will fix it.

Comment: Last question - a bit ot though, sorry for that - so the techie007-monster wont jump me anymore: how do I make the editor create such a code box ... or is it something else?

Comment: Very last question: How do I reward you Ramhound? Or did I do so by marking your answer as the solution?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the solution, because I had a similar problem with Emsisoft Internet Security a few weeks ago. But Emsisoft sayd that they patched it already which was true for several other PCs but for some reason .. not for this one. But I'll update if it didnt help.

Comment: Should be easy enough to confirm.  Duplicate the crash conditions, with the patch/resolution, and you should be golden.  I just want to make sure we solve the problem instead of just throw it under the rug.

Comment: @Akil: The fact that WinDbg couldn't load symbols for that driver tells you that it didn't come from Microsoft. (There are exceptions to this, but they're rare. Also, some non-MS drivers do have symbols in the MS symbol store that WinDbg uses. But anyway.) Now, not all non-MS drivers are bad, or should be removed, or etc. But when a non-MS-supplied driver appears on the stack during a crash, that's your first suspect.

Comment: @ Jamie Hanrahan Thanks, that explains a lot :) I will try to keep it in mind for the next BSOD-problem.
@ Ramhound Unfortunately I cannot duplicate the crash condidtions because sometimes it happened after 20min of work and sometimes after 6hrs. So I think only time can tell. Next ot question .. how can u force the comment editor to make a <br>? While typing it works with shift+enter but after saving its gone :/

Comment: @Akil - You don't.  If you feel comfortable with saying this is an answer then I am happy I was able to determine the problem.

Comment: 8 days later still no BSOD! :D